# How to skip columns when making a pandas DataFrame from bs4?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table off of a website using Python and BeautifulSoup4. I then want to output the table, but I want to skip the first 5 columns of the table. Here is my code

```
def scrape_data():
    url1 = "https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html"
    html1 = urlopen(url1)
    soup1 = bs(html1, 'html.parser')
    soup1.findAll('tr', limit = 2)
    headers1 = [th.getText() for th in soup1.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
    headers1 = headers1[5:]
    rows1 = soup1.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows1[i].findAll('td')]for i in range(len(rows1))]
    stats1 = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns=headers1)
    return stats1
```

And the error I get is `ValueError: 24 columns passed, passed data had 28 columns`

I know the error is coming from `stats1 = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns=headers1)`

But how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you not just slice off the appropriate amount of columns when building your table, eg: `for td in rows1[i].findAll('td')` would become `for td in rows1[i].findAll('td')[5:]` ...?

Comment: Also the camel case names have been deprecated or a while and using `select` is also an option here... so you could do `player_stats = [[td.get_text() for td in tr.select('td')[5:]] for tr in soup1.select('tr')[1:]]` ?

Comment: @JonClements I’ll give that a shot. Are you saying the DataFrame shouldn’t be camel case? Before I added [5:] it worked fine, the error isn’t camelcase

Comment: Nah... I'm saying for beautifulsoup... things like `.getText()` and `.findAll` are deprecated... they're `get_text()` and `find_all()` now - so best to get in the habit of using those because (no idea when) but they're likely to be going to go away at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `iloc` on the resulting dataframe.  Note that `read_html` returns a list of dataframes, although there is only one per this url.  You need to access this single dataframe via `pd.read_html(url)[0]`.  Then just use `iloc` to ignore the first five columns.

```
url = "https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0].iloc[:, 5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to some help from @JonClements. My working code is

```
def scrape_data():
    url1 = "https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html"
    html1 = urlopen(url1)
    soup1 = bs(html1, 'html.parser')
    soup1.findAll('tr', limit = 2)
    headers1 = [th.getText() for th in soup1.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
    headers1 = headers1[5:]
    rows1 = soup1.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows1[i].findAll('td')[4:]]for i in range(len(rows1))]
    stats1 = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns=headers1)
    return stats1
```